# How to test an authorization redirect with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have manually tested the scenario I want:

Admin Users can go to the `/codes` section of the site.
Normal users are redirected (302) back to the `/dashboard` and have a message `Sorry you are not allowed there` when they go to `/qr`.

Manual testing passes, yet laravel testing fails.

I am using `laravel 5.1`

**Test for the admin user:**

```
public function testAdminViewCodes()
    {
        //create an admin user
        $user = factory(App\User::class, 'admin')->create();

        $this->actingAs($user)
            ->visit('/codes')
            ->seePageIs('/codes')
            ->see('Codes');
    }
```

**Test for normal user:**

```
    public function testNormalViewCodesFail()
    {
        //create a normal user
        $normal_user = factory(App\User::class)->create();

        //TODO: Fix this failing test FFS

        $this->actingAs($normal_user)
             ->visit('/qr')
             ->seePageIs('/dashboard')
             ->see('Sorry you are not allowed there');
}
```

**test results**;

```
There was 1 failure:

1) AdminTest::testNormalViewQRCodesFail
Did not land on expected page [http://localhost/dashboard].

Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'http://localhost/dashboard'
+'http://localhost/codes'
```

I think there may be an issue with the factories, seems to be always creating an admin user:

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'email' => $faker->email,
        'password' => bcrypt(str_random(10)),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
        'is_admin' => false,
    ];
});

$factory->defineAs(App\User::class, 'admin', function ($faker) use ($factory) {
    $user = $factory->raw(App\User::class);

    return array_merge($user, ['is_admin' => true]);
});
```

My apologies for how long this question is, but there is another pertanent issue. I am using `middleware` to test whether the user is admin:

```
<?php

namespace RMS\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class IsAdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (app()->env === 'testing') {
            return $next($request);
        }

        if (! $request->user()->isAdmin()) {
          return redirect()->route('dashboard')
              ->with('message', 'Sorry you are not allowed there');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

In `Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \RMS\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \RMS\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'isadmin' => \RMS\Http\Middleware\IsAdminMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

And applied to routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'isadmin']], function()
{
    Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
});
```

Is Middleware ignored? I was sure not to add the `use WithoutMiddleware;` statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two options:

- better create tests for user factory, like it can make user types you want
- break with a debugger after user generation to inspect it manually

I recommend you to create tests, beacuse you have doubt now, and in future there is a chance of accidently breaking the factory code, since it's not so obvious.

Comment: `break with a debugger after user generation to inspect it manually` how do you do this. With python there is a cool tool called `pdb()` and `ipdb()` is there an equivalent for laravel?

Comment: Debugger for PHP is called [XDebug](https://xdebug.org/). There is integrated support in some IDEs, for example - [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/configuring-xdebug.html).

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't let you inspect in the middle of interpretation...or does it?

Comment: It does, also it allows you to change variables in runtime and evaluate custom code. When you get used to it, you can debug times faster than with var_dump or similar.

Comment: I see that it works when integrating with an IDE, what is your IDE of preference?

Answer (score 8):

As an aside: [unit tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) are not meant to be `user experience` tests. For that is would be `acceptance` or `functional` testing. One of the more popular tools for that is [codeception](http://codeception.com/). It combined with [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) or [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) can emulate a browser session and get full user experience rendering.

Per docs available at http://codeception.com/docs/01-Introduction docs:

**Acceptance Tests** : 'Acceptance tests can cover standard but complex scenarios from a user’s perspective. With acceptance tests you can be confident that users, following all defined scenarios, won’t get errors.'

**Functional Tests** : 'functional tests you emulate a web request ($_GET and $_POST variables) and send it into your application which returns HTML response. '

**Unit Tests** : 'Testing pieces of code before coupling them together is highly important as well. This way you can be sure that some deeply hidden feature still works, even if it was not covered by functional or acceptance tests. This also proves that you produced stable and testable code.'

Comment: It's not a unit test, but functional test with the help of Laravel [built-it testing tools](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing).

Comment: @Pheagey Please write the definitions of the different kinds of tests in your answer and then link to a credible resource. Wikipedia does not cut it. I will change the question as soon as I am clear if it is a `unit`, `functional`, `integration` or `end-to-end` test. Is this an answer, or an aside/comment?

Comment: Had to remove you as the accepted answer as you are not answering the question. I am testing authorization, I did not mention that it is a unit test.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using Authenticate a User Instance `Auth::login($user);` for more details read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#other-authentication-methods).

This method is valid for Laravel 5.x and up

Comment: Ah that is `laravel 5.2` I mentioned I was on `laravel 5.1`. The upgrade seemed a bit too much.

Comment: this method is also valid for 5.1 as well https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#other-authentication-methods

Comment: Ok, but I am already doing this I think with the `actingAs` helper method https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#sessions-and-authentication

Comment: Let me dig in it and get back to you